# Get-AzResourceGroup returns "No tenant found in the context"

Tags: azure-powershell

I've just opened PowerShell and ran:

```
> Connect-AzAccount
> Get-AzResourceGroup
```

And received this error.

> Get-AzResourceGroup: No tenant found in the context.  Please ensure that the credentials you provided are authorized to access an Azure subscription, then run Connect-AzAccount to login.

```
> Get-AzSubscription
```

> WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'Common'

> Get-AzSubscription: Could not authenticate with tenant . Please ensure that your account has access to this tenant and log in with Connect-AzAccount

I've not used Azure PowerShell for a year. I copy pasted the URL given to me by the connect command into the same browser as I have my Azure subscription open in and logged in as per usual. I'm the sole admin and user on my Azure sub. Here's my version.

```
> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      1      4
```

I tried to reinstall the Azure PowerShell module but got further strangeness.

```
> Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
Install-Package: C:\program files\powershell\7\Modules\PowerShellGet\PSModule.psm1:9711
Line |
9711 |  … talledPackages = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters                                                                                                           |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Administrator rights are required to install or update. Log on to the computer with an account that has Administrator rights, and then try again, or install by
     | adding "-Scope CurrentUser" to your command. You can also try running the Windows PowerShell session with elevated rights (Run as Administrator).
```

Obviously, I'm running as admin and I have specified the `CurrentUser` scope. I will give up and try the Azure CLI.

Raised an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/15842

Comment: What does `Get-AzContext` pipe to output?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara Well that spewed a whole table of correct looking stuff out, so I tried `Get-AzResourceGroup` again and now it works. The only thing I've done since I posted was install Google Cloud CLI and then install the Azure CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think installing the Azure CLI resolved it.

I've literally only done these things since posting.

- Installed the Google Cloud CLI and GCP SDK.
- Spend 10 hours reading the GCP documentation on a bunch of stuff because I was interested in seeing how green their grass really is.
- Tried and failed to install a different Az PS package as request by someone on the Github issue.
- Tried and successfully installed the Microsoft.Graph PS package, again as a test requested by my Github friend.
- Installed the Azure CLI via MSI.
- Read the comment from @BhargaviAnnadevara and tried it and saw that it all worked.